# Как получить через регулярку в Xml слова, перед которыми стоит символ >, но не включая его?

Tags: xml

Я пишу регулярные выражения для AvalonEdit (редактор кода), чтобы подсвечивать синтаксис PHP.

```
$this->clientSize = dnn ('System.Drawing.Size', 344, 321);
$this->controls->add ($this->button1);
$this->name = 'Form1';
$this->text = 'Form1';
$this->resumeLayout (false);
```

Нужна такая регулярка, которая подсвечивает имена свойств. Пробую примерно так:

```
<Rule color="Black">
    [\>]*[\d\w_]+
</Rule>
```

С регулярными выражениями работал редко, подскажите, как правильно написать.

Comment: [Просмотр вперёд и назад](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регулярные_выражения#Просмотр_вперёд_и_назад). Что-то вроде: `(?<=>)*[\d\w_]+`

Comment: Это бесполезно, поскольку регулярные выражения Xml "не терпят" знак равно в начале строки. Знак "=", шестнадцатеричное значение 0x3D, не может стоять в начале имени., строка 93, позиция 7. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Знак "=", шестнадцатеричное значение 0x3D, не может стоять в начале имени., строка 93, позиция 7.

Comment: Вы спросили про регулярку - я вам ответил. Теперь у вас возник вопрос, как экранировать значения в xml. Какого ... вы пишете в комментариях то, что должно быть задано отдельным вопросом?